# How to fix the 'pre' tag's issues with left angle brackets '<'?

Tags: html, escaping, syntax-highlighting, pre

I hear this is a long-standing issue with the 'pre' tags — when you are displaying a code block inside `<pre>` tags, you need to escape all instances of `<` (left angle brackets).

Is there an automatic fix for this? — (I mean) so that I don't have to manually replace all instances of `<` with `&lt;` in every post I make.

Comment: Escaping them _is_ "the fix".

Comment: &gt; &lt; or use a function to do it.

Comment: @Madbreaks : I am looking for an automatic way to achieve it, so that I don't to manually do it in every post I make.

Comment: In PHP using htmlspecialchars function should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Suggestion as an "Auto" fix of sorts, is a str_replace on the string your putting into your pre tag. Assuming of course your using PHP, but each language has its equivalent I suppose.

```
<pre>
<?php
  $str = $variable_of_stuff_going_into_pre;
  $str = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $str);
  $str = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $str);
  echo $str;
 ?>
 </pre>
```

That's kind of a simplified version of it. You can use arrays are your search/replace string as well.